# How to add/create custom position in footer.tpl for opencart 2.0

Tags: module, position, opencart, footer

I am trying to add a custom positions in the footer for opencart 2.0.

I successfully added other custom positions in home like "content_middle" etc, but when I added new position into footer.tpl/footer.php etc, and goto
"System > Design > Layouts > Home" and added the module + position, it does not show in homepage, does anyone know why or what I did wrong? thank you

Comment: I checked my code and am unable to find anything wrong with it, if I add new position in home.tpl etc it works, but when I add new position in footer.tpl, it wont show :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out the cause of the problem...

Seems that alot of things have changed from Opencart 1.5 to Opencart 2.0

I found out that the 'custom position' title cannot be longer than 14 char

because in the database the 'custom position' name field column can only contain '14 char' (varchar(14)), so anything longer than 14 char ( e.g. 'footer_copyright', 'footer_content_copyright' etc ) will only have the first 14 char stored in database (footer_copyright will become footer_copyrig) Thus, the 'custom position' will not work, even if you done everything correctly.

Still I do not understand why limit to only 14 characters?

Can anyone tell me why?